# What is the difference between $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and $HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: php

I'm looking in an old script.
I found a code :

```
ereg($self_name, $HTTP_REFERER)
```

Can I change that code to the following code?:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
```

or change it to

```
preg_match("%$self_name%", $HTTP_REFERER)
```

What is the difference between `$HTTP_REFERER` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ?

note:

```
//Site name for security checks:
$self_name = '.*';
```

Comment: the old `$HTTP_*` vars are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. They're a relic from early PHP days, and have been replaced with the the various $_WHATEVER superglobals. Major diff (beyond names) is that that $HTTP vars aren't superglobal - they exist only at the top level scope in PHP.

Comment: Thank you , I got my answer. can you please tell me about first question?

Comment: `ereg` is also deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Some times $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) is empty. and it's not a good idea to check a form with this code preg_match("%$self_name%", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])). isit right? @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ereg()` and `$HTTP_REFERER` are both deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead you may use:

```
preg_match("%$self_name%", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Note that :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
```

only checks if referer is set or not, but

```
preg_match("%$self_name%", $HTTP_REFERER)
```

checks if that referer is in `$self_name` or not.

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP_REFERER` and the `$ereg` are left over from at latest, PHP4, they are *DEPRECATED* as of PHP5 and **REMOVED** in PHP7.

> ```
> ereg($self_name, $HTTP_REFERER)
> ```
>
> Can I change that code to the following code?:
>
> ```
> if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
> ```

This checks if `$self_name` is in the referring URI.

Some points to note:

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is the PHP5,PHP7 + equivilant of the older `$HTTP_` value.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is often not set or at best can be unreliable and should not be trusted for any remotely critical code decisions.
- If you want to check if the pageloads is coming from another page on the same site it may be easier to use a `$_SESSION` variable,
- To check PCRE value regex use `preg_` functions such as [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
- you `$self_name` value of `.*` means "any character any number of times" (except new lines), which is extremely non-specific catch all.
- It looks like you're simply checking if the `$self_name` is in the string in which case it's faster to use [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

So taking all of the above into account you can replace the `ereg` line with:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$something) !== false){
    //Yes, page was referred by URL like $something. 
}
```

Comment: +1 for f(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$self_name) !== false){
    //found. 
}

Comment: @Rudie I really should not just skim read the manual pages of deprecated functions. Cheers. Updated.